# Why isn't the www. for my domain working on Github Pages?

Tags: github, dns, hosting, web-hosting, github-pages

My forwarded domain only works on example.com but doesn't work on www.example.com

I have everything setup like i am supposed to. My repository is named user.github.io. I have a cname file with my url example.com.

I forwarded my domain to the ip like below. I am using Name.com as my domain registar.

[image]

Now my domain works when i go to example.com but when i type www.example.com it doesn't work. I thought both were supposed to work.

I have tried my cname file with www.example.com and change my dns forwards to www.example.com but then only www.example.com works and example.com doesn't work.

How do i get both to work?

Comment: You need A records for *both* `www.example.com` and `example.com` if you want this to work. Incidentally, make sure one of the two issues nothing but HTTP permanent redirects to the other.

Comment: Why didn't i think of this before. I just set up a redirect so example.com redirects to www.example.com and that works.